# magento2 developer mode not properly set

Tags: frontend, magento2.2, developer-mode

I would like to change the workflow type to client side, but when I navigate to this configuration option, it tells me that this option is not available in production mode. 
[image]
I've set magento to developer mode with `magento deploy:mode:set developer` multiple times, I've cleared everything in `var/cache`, `var/view_preprocessed`, `pub/static` and cleaned the cache, but no change. I've also set it to production mode and then back to developer mode, that didn't help either. Last but not least I just changed the config in `app/etc/config.php` and imported the config, but then the app just keeps telling me `The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration.`
I don't know what else to try, can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

the comment "not available in production mode" is just a hint, that this setting will not be used in production mode - developer mode will not make this field editable.

So setting the developer mode with the console command was the correct first step.
To verify if developer mode is enabled you can use the following command:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

The field being not enabled / greyed out is another thing from the [pipeline deployment](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/deployment/) feature, introduced with magento 2.2.

You can change the setting via a console command:

```
bin/magento config:set --lock dev/front_end_development_workflow/type client_side_compilation
```

Comment: thanks, `deploy:mode:show` shows that the mode is set to developer. I just noticed that my whole config tree seems to be locked somehow. I can't uncheck any of the `Use system value` checkboxes and other changes just don't take effect, although I get a confirmation after saving the config. Is it possible to lock/unlock the whole config tree?

Comment: ok, that seems to be why: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196912/appconfigdump-locks-everything-in-configuration. I could set it with `config:set` and then dump the config again, all good. Thanks a lot.