# Magento 2.3 - Can't change any settings in backend

Tags: magento2.3, theme

**EDIT:** I noticed that I can't change any setting anymore! It just resets after save to the old value. No error message is shown.

Old Title: Theme does not change, even though database value changes
If I change the theme in **Content -> Design -> Configuration**

Then it always changes back to the old theme even though I can see that the value is changed in the database. (Table "core_config_data" -> path: "design/theme/theme_id")

If I reload the frontend, then it still loads the old theme though.

How can I fix this bug? I already cleared the cache with

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that I executed `php bin/magento app:config:dump` which changed the files `app/etc/env.php` and `app/etc/config.php`.

I found the answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/252740/66769).

You have to edit the file `app/etc/config.php`.
Remove everything but the modules array and then save.
Then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: I am getting  below error after run php  bin/magento app:config:import  or setup:upgrade ::

Processing configurations data from configuration file...
Import failed: Area code is not set